# Typing Spanish characters into VBE

Tags: vba

I have to type Spanish character (ñ) in VBE but I get n instead of ñ. I'm using polish version of Excel. Do you know how I can change that?

Comment: It's nor really a VBA question, but what you need to do is to add Spanish language in your "Language Preferences" settings.

Comment: You can't type this character in VBE, but you can still process it. For example put this char in cell A1 and run this code: `Sub test()
    Dim myChar As String: myChar = Range("a1"): Range("a2") = myChar
End Sub` The workaround is to store and get these characters from cells. However, it's better to simply use `ChrW()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're typing the letter into a string then you can use the chr function. For example:

```
mystring = "jalepe" & chr(164) & "o"
```

It lengthens what should be simple strings, but it gets the work done.

If you need ñ for a function name or something similar, then hod's comment to your question should help you.